# Now I'm using flutter 3.3.9 version, if i used upgrade comment to the cmd the below error occur

Tags: flutter, dart, upgrade

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2EhN.png)

When i run 'flutter upgrade' in cmd and then the error pop up. How to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Your error message shows that you've used command `flutter update` but you need to use `flutter upgrade`